# Angular 2+: data binding using Subjects is not working in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-observable

I need to communicate data between two component while the page is also changing. To do this, I implemented a data service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DatashareService {
    public dataSubject = new Subject<any>();
    public addData(data){
        this.dataSubject.next(data);
    }
}
```

and pass data to it using addData method:

```
export class DashboardDialog {
    dashboardName;
    dashboardDescription;
    .....
    addElements() {
            this.dataShare.addData({dashboardName: "a name", dashboardDescription:"a description"});
            this.router.navigate(["dashboards/new"]);
            this.closeDialog();
        }
    }
```

I subscribed to its data in my other component:

```
export class NewDashboardDesign implements OnInit {
    dashboardName;
    xmlContent;
    constructor(private dataShare: DatashareService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataShare.dataSubject.subscribe(
            data => {
                this.dashboardName = data.dashboardName;           
                this.xmlContent = "<dashboard>\n" +
                    sprintf("<name> '%s' </name>\n", this.dashboardName) +
                    "</dashboard>\n";
            }
        );
    }
```

However, my html element does not get updated with the new content (although I get the data):

```
<mat-form-field>
   <textarea matInput placeholder="XML" [(ngModel)]='xmlContent' #xml></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Where do you call the addData() method of the service? Is the NewDashboardDesign already created when this method is called? How are is the service provided to the components? Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. We can't guess what your code is.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console? If you set `this.xmlContent = "Hello world"` in the subscribe handler, does it work?

Comment: as far as I can see, you neither invoke getData or declare the service as provider somewhere in the sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume from your description that the two Components between which you are attempting to communicate are both 'top-level' components (you are routing from one to the other).

This means that the two of them are never in existence at the same time.
So, the first component is 'publishing' via the DatashareService, but the second component is not there to receive the data. The subscription happens after the event is emitted.

To fix this, change your Subject to a BehaviorSubject. Unlike Subject, BehaviorSubject emits the last event upon subscription.